# Rails uniq Public Activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, public-activity

```
t = PublicActivity::Activity.arel_table

@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(
    (t[:trackable_type].eq("Lesson").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_lessons_ids)))
    .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Post").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_posts_ids)))
    .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("WallPost").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_wallposts_ids)))
    .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Comment").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_comments_ids)))
    .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Course").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_courses_ids)))
    .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Group").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_groups_ids)))
).order("id DESC").uniq{|a| "#{a.trackable_type}-#{a.trackable_id}"}
```

In my database I have duplicate entries for "Trackable_type"+"trackable_id" because if a user click on "update" many times I get many entries.
So, I want only to get one of these. 
I tried with 
`.uniq{|a| "#{a.trackable_type}-#{a.trackable_id}"}`

but nothing happens.

Returned SQL QUERY:

> "SELECT DISTINCT \"activities\".* FROM \"activities\" WHERE
>   (((((\"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'Lesson' AND
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (11, 39, 40, 16, 5, 3, 12, 9, 13,
>   19, 18, 37, 15, 23, 24, 29, 20, 10, 25, 26, 27, 17, 28, 22, 21, 30,
>   33, 35, 34, 36, 32, 31) OR \"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'Post'
>   AND \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44,
>   43, 42, 41, 40, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25,
>   24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 14, 13, 12, 10, 5)) OR
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'WallPost' AND
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (158, 157, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151,
>   132, 131, 130, 129, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115,
>   114, 113, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100,
>   99, 98, 93, 92, 91, 90, 87, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76,
>   75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59,
>   58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42,
>   41, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22,
>   20, 19, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4)) OR
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'Comment' AND
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (100, 99, 98, 95, 83, 82, 81, 79,
>   78, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 65, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 52,
>   51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35,
>   34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18,
>   17, 16, 15, 14)) OR \"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'Course' AND
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (8, 1, 5, 7)) OR
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_type\" = 'Group' AND
>   \"activities\".\"trackable_id\" IN (14, 11, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1))  ORDER
>   BY id DESC"

**UPDATE:**

if I try:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.select("distinct trackable_type, trackable_id").where(
        (t[:trackable_type].eq("Lesson").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_lessons_ids)))
        .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Post").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_posts_ids)))
        .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("WallPost").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_wallposts_ids)))
        .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Comment").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_comments_ids)))
        .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Course").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_courses_ids)))
        .or(t[:trackable_type].eq("Group").and(t[:trackable_id].in(@my_groups_ids)))
    ).order("id DESC")
```

I get this:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

If I try

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.select("DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *")
```

I get

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *) FR... ^ : SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *) FROM "activities"
```

Comment: Try This `.uniq{|a| a.trackable_type && a.trackable_id }`

Comment: What DB client you using ? MySql, Postgresql.. ?

Comment: @sparkle do this `PublicActivity.select("distinct trackable_type, trackable_id")`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query without `arel` will be :

```
PublicActivity::Activity.select("DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *")
              .where("(trackable_type = ? and trackable_id IN (?))
                      or (trackable_type = ? and trackable_id IN (?))",
                      "Lesson", @my_lessons_ids,
                      "Post", @my_post_ids)
```

Comment: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *) FR... ^ : SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *) FROM "activities" WHERE ((trackable_type = 'Lesson' and trackable_id IN (11,39,40,16,5,3,12,9,13,19,18,37,15,23,24,29,20,10,25,26,27,17,28,22,21,30,33,35,34,36,32,31)) or (trackable_type = 'Post' and trackable_id IN (NULL)))

Comment: I do this: PublicActivity::Activity.select("DISTINCT ON(trackable_type, trackable_id) *") maybe is something with "PublicActivity::Activity" ?

Comment: Ok, the problem was with "kaminari". Do you a way to order by id DESC?

Comment: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: @sparkle Well.. It seems some default scope from your app was getting inserted. Read [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). Yes.. *The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.*